# Explanation of build_vocab in torch and it's association with pre-trained embeddings

Tags: nlp, pytorch, torchtext

Can some explain me what is build_vocab in torch, it is not clear from online documentation? Why do we need it and it's relation to pre-trained embeddings?

Comment: Please add references to he online documentation, ideally with the help of excerpts that clearly relate to your problem of understanding. Consider taking a look at [ask] to improve the current state of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse `pytorch` and `torchtext` here. In `torchtext` *(a package that provides processing utilities and popular datasets for natural language)* you can run `build_vocab` of a `Field` to iterate over your dataset in order to build up the vocabulary.

*Take also a look here:

https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Field.build_vocab*